# UWP settings of InAppNotification

Tags: c#, uwp

Help me somebody. I try to use InAppNotification to message to user but I do something wrong.

When I click on the button message i will see the message but it transparent or in the background and I can’t figure out how to bring to front DataGrid.
Look picture. [Wrong InAppNotification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTfTA.jpg)

```
<Page
    x:Class="ComboBoxColumnBorderColor.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ComboBoxColumnBorderColor"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:MSControls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Content="Click me"
                Click="Button_Click"
                Margin="10">
        </Button>

        <MSControls:InAppNotification Grid.Row="1"
                                      x:Name="MessageForUser"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                      Background="Green"
                                      BorderBrush="Red">

        </MSControls:InAppNotification>


        <MSControls:DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Companies}"
                             x:Name="MyDataGrid"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                             RowHeight="60">

            <MSControls:DataGrid.Columns>

                <MSControls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Company Name" 
                                               Binding="{Binding Name}"/>

                <MSControls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Company Name" 
                                               Binding="{Binding Description}"/>

                <MSControls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Company Name" 
                                               Binding="{Binding Address}"/>

            </MSControls:DataGrid.Columns>

        </MSControls:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Page>

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MainPageVM();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageForUser.Show("Hello User!", 3000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put at **InAppNotification** last in XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="ComboBoxColumnBorderColor.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ComboBoxColumnBorderColor"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:MSControls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Content="Click me"
                Click="Button_Click"
                Margin="10">
        </Button>




        <MSControls:DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Companies}"
                             x:Name="MyDataGrid"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                             RowHeight="60">

            <MSControls:DataGrid.Columns>

                <MSControls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Company Name" 
                                               Binding="{Binding Name}"/>

                <MSControls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Company Name" 
                                               Binding="{Binding Description}"/>

                <MSControls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Company Name" 
                                               Binding="{Binding Address}"/>

            </MSControls:DataGrid.Columns>

        </MSControls:DataGrid>

        <MSControls:InAppNotification Grid.Row="1"
                                      x:Name="MessageForUser"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                      Background="Green"
                                      BorderBrush="Red">

        </MSControls:InAppNotification>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Yes, the xaml layout as layers, the first element you wrote lays in bottom. The last element lays on topest. Ive already post a repo in your another question.